# Why is studying centralizers the/a key to classifying finite groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups, big-picture

In this MO thread https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38161/heuristic-argument-that-finite-simple-groups-ought-to-be-classifiable, Borcherds says

> One problem, as least with the current methods of classification via centralizers of involutions, is that every simple group has to be tested to see if it leads to new simple groups containing it in the centralizer of an involution. For example, when the baby monster was discovered, it had a double cover, which was a potential centralizer of an involution in a larger simple group, which turned out to be the monster.

The basic theorem about centralizers and involutions is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer%E2%80%93Fowler_theorem, whose Wikipedia page states

> Perhaps more important is another result that the authors derive from the same count of involutions, namely that up to isomorphism there are only a finite number of finite simple groups with a given centralizer of an involution. This suggested that finite simple groups could be classified by studying their centralizers of involutions, and it led to the discovery of several sporadic groups. Later it motivated a part of the classification of finite simple groups.

Here are some neat write-ups on Brauer-Fowler that I thought were nice: http://thomasbloom.org/notes/brauer.html, https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/quasirandom-groups-and-a-cheap-version-of-the-brauer-fowler-theorem/.

Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups#Timeline_of_the_proof, we see that

> 1955  The Brauer–Fowler theorem implies that the number of finite simple groups with given centralizer of involution is finite, suggesting an attack on the classification using centralizers of involutions.
>
> ...
>
> 1957  Suzuki shows that all finite simple CA groups of odd order are cyclic.
>
> ...
>
> 1960  Feit, Marshall Hall, and Thompson show that all finite simple CN groups of odd order are cyclic.
>
> ...
>
> 1963  Feit and Thompson prove the odd order theorem.

Where CA and CN stand for "all centralizers are abelian" and "all centralizers are nilpotent". This article [https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~eal/Suzukithm.pdf](https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/%7Eeal/Suzukithm.pdf) points out the relation between the CA, CN, and Feit-Thompson theorems:

- The CA theorem tells us that groups whose non-identity elements have *abelian* centralizers are solvable.
- The CN theorem tells us that groups whose non-identity elements have *nilpotent* centralizers are solvable.
- The F-T theorem tells us/is equivalent to the statement that odd-order groups whose non-identity elements have *solvable* centralizers are solvable.

That article also says that

> In the odd order
> paper Feit and Thompson proceed by analyzing the structure of the centralizers inside a
> hypothetical minimal counterexample to their theorem.

In this [blogpost](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/04/12/the-theorems-of-frobenius-and-suzuki-on-finite-groups/), Terry Tao describes a "ladder" to the [CFSG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups), with rungs in particular going from CA theorem (to the CN theorem) to the F-T theorem.

**In summary**: going up this ladder we are considering groups with (progressively less and less) nice properties regarding the centralizers of elements and still trying to prove that it is solvable (resulting in the CA, CN, and F-T theorems); and in the separate (but still related of course) subject of finding new simple groups, as Borcherds said we again focus on centralizers (this time of just involutions).

So it appears that at many different stages of proving the CFSG --- from the very "beginning" in "[1955](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups#Timeline_of_the_proof) The Brauer–Fowler theorem implies that the number of finite simple groups with given centralizer of involution is finite, suggesting an attack on the classification using centralizers of involutions.", to the late stage of discovering the Monster group --- people relied on this philosophy/idea of focusing on/studying centralizers.

> **Question:** why is this? Why should having some information on what elements commute with each other in a group, and/or properties about that set of commuting elements (e.g. that it is abelian, nilpotent, etc.), tell you things about the group as a whole, and moreover give classification results about whole families of groups?

---

---

---

P.S. in the above-linked [Terry blogpost on Brauer-Fowler](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/quasirandom-groups-and-a-cheap-version-of-the-brauer-fowler-theorem/#cho), Terry does say

> ...the actual proof of the CFSG does not quite proceed along these lines. However, a significant portion of the argument is based on a generalisation of this strategy, in which the concept of a centraliser of an involution is replaced by the more general notion of a normaliser of a {p}-group, and one studies not just a single normaliser but rather the entire family of such normalisers and how they interact with each other (and in particular, which normalisers of {p}-groups commute with each other), motivated in part by the theory of Tits buildings for Lie groups...

So perhaps I am giving the centralizer-strategy a little too much credit. But [Terry's blogpost on the Frobenius and Suzuki theorems](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/04/12/the-theorems-of-frobenius-and-suzuki-on-finite-groups/) linked this [very detailed (and a bit technical) survey by Solomon](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2001-38-03/S0273-0979-01-00909-0/S0273-0979-01-00909-0.pdf), and Ctrl-F "CG" finds occurences of centralizers $C_G(\bullet)$ all over the place (along with of course other fancier subgroups: Fitting subgroup, Thompson subgroup, maximal normal semisimple subgroups, generalized Fitting subgroups, p-layer subgroups, etc.). Regardless, I think the main body of my post makes it clear that the centralizer-strategy was quite important and pursued/utilized in many different areas, and I would appreciate any insight as to why.

Comment: +1 from me for the nice write-up of the history and relevant links! Burnside already conjectured that non-abelian finite simple groups must have even order (which is equivalent to finite groups of odd order groups are solvable). So Cauchy's Theorem guarantees the existence of elements of order $2$ in non-abelian simple groups. The proof of Brauer-Fowler then hints at looking at centralisers of these elements.

Comment: @NickyHekster yeah, that seems to be the historical development. My question is about the "creative leap", going from this (rather meager, in my opinion...) hint from Brauer-Fowler that centralizers of involutions are important, to a grander strategy of studying centralizers in general, and in particular studying what results from a bunch of properties we can ask centralizers to satisfy.

Comment: Centralizers of involutions are a special case of local subgroups (i.e. normalizers $N_G(Q)$ for $Q$ a $p$-group), which are important in CFSG. In Notices of the AMS there is a paper "The status of the classification of the finite simple groups." by Aschbacher which explains the strategy a bit more. I'm not sure if you will really get an explanation other than it just turns out to be successful.

Comment: I am not an expert on the classification, but I sometimes think of it this way. If you have a non-abelian finite simple group $G$, because there are no normal subgroups, it is really difficult to pin down the structure of $G$. (You cannot reduce questions to smaller groups, etc.) So you look at subgroups of $G$ which do have normal subgroups (normalizers, centralizers) that you might have a chance of understanding, and thus giving some hints about the structure of $G$.